# HTML link scroll down the page

Tags: html, hyperlink

```
     <div class="menu right-float clearfix">
  <nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
     <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#home" class="scroll-to">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#gaelic" class="scroll-to">Gaelic Sports</a></li>
     <li><a href="#soccer" class="scroll-to">Soccer</a></li>
     <li><a href="#cricket" class="scroll-to">India Cricket</a></li>
     <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll-to">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#basket" class="scroll-to">BasketBall</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
 <nav id="menu-controls">
  <ul>
   <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#home" class="scroll-to"><span class="c-dot"></span><span class="c-name">Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#gaelic" class="scroll-to"><span class="c-dot"></span><span class="c-name">Gaelic Sports</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#soccer" class="scroll-to"><span class="c-dot"></span><span class="c-name">Soccer</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#cricket" class="scroll-to"><span class="c-dot"></span><span class="c-name">India Cricket</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll-to"><span class="c-dot"></span><span class="c-name">Contact</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#basket" class="scroll-to"><span class="c-dot"></span><span class="c-name">BasketBall</span></a></li>

 </ul>
```

I have a question about HTML links. I added the last line in the code shown above. If I click on the Soccer link, the page will scroll down to the bottom and will show me the soccer information. I want to click Basketball link and have it scroll down and show me the basketball page. I am updating the index file. Is there any good solution? Thanks.

Comment: All the links are working perfect accept basketball which i added myself.

Comment: you can do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/r03jz112/2/

Comment: Did you make a basket HTML page? Is any link associated with an HTML page? Give more information please.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply. i did not add any html page www.feed-from-the-field.com is the website i am updating. if you have a look and see all the links are working accept basketball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly add `<a href="#basketball"></a>` just like the previous one.

Comment: feed-from-the-field.com is the website i am updating

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the anchor in at the destination.

For all of the working links, you will probably see a `id="gaelic"` on a tag, you need to add one of these for basketball.

Comment: is there a css file for that to add id=basketball because i cant find this link in any where????

Comment: The `#` symbol in the link destination is pointing to a tag on the page that you are working on; the page will scroll so that tag is visible. If there's nothing with the ID of 'basketball' on that page, the browser won't scroll it.